# Fibers error while upgrading project node version from 8.10 to latest version 12

Tags: node.js, webpack, node-gyp, fibers

I have upgraded node version 8 to 12 and then deleted node_modules and package-lock.json then i have run the below cmd to upgrade all the compatible modules.

```
npm update
```

then, while doing "npm install", getting this error

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\Ramya\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.18.4\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Ramya\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v12.18.4\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\TT-workspace\selfcarewebui\node_modules\fibers
gyp ERR! node -v v12.18.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-gyp exited with code: 1
Please make sure you are using a supported platform and node version. If you
would like to compile fibers on this machine please make sure you have setup your
build environment--
Windows + OS X instructions here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp
Ubuntu users please run: `sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential`
RHEL users please run: `yum install gcc-c++` and `yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'`
Alpine users please run: `sudo apk add python make g++`
'nodejs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.0: wanted: {"node":"<8.10.0"} (current: {"node":"12.18.4","npm":"6.14.6"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.0
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\webpack\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\karma\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN angular-material@1.0.8 requires a peer of angular-mocks@>=1.3 <1.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-material@1.0.8 requires a peer of angular-route@>=1.3 <1.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN autoprefixer@10.0.0 requires a peer of postcss@^8.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN extract-text-webpack-plugin@1.0.1 requires a peer of webpack@^1.9.11 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN acorn-jsx@5.3.1 requires a peer of acorn@^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN selfcarewebui@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! fibers@3.1.1 install: `node build.js || nodejs build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@3.1.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Old version details

- Node.js: v8.10.0
- npm: v5.7.1